# Having org-mode beamer / latex to ignore below a certain tag

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

I want to speedup compilation by instructing org-mode/latex/beamer to ignore everything coming after it.

My document takes a bit of time to process code with pigment and the like

Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark headings with tags, and set options for [including and excluding](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) tags from export.

E.g.

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: slow

* My work
** This section takes time   :slow:
** This other section is OK
```